# Invalidate a specific cache tag on any saved taxonomy term

Tags: 8, nodes, caching

I would like to clear cache tag of a particular bundle when any taxonomy terms are update/ saved.

I know the default node tag is saved like node:1, node:2, but I'm confused on how to invalidate a particular bundle.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't invalidate entity tags, Drupal does this automatically on CRUD operations.

Instead add a cache tag to all nodes of the specific content type:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_node()
 *
 */
function mymodule_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['node']->getType() === 'my_content_type') {
    $variables['#cache']['tags'][] = 'taxonomy_term_list';
  }
}
```

The tag `taxonomy_term_list` gets invalidated on any taxonomy term saved/updated/deleted.

Comment: This works, but it would affect all terms, it is more likely that you'd want do this only with terms from a specific vocabulary. Then you do need to define your own tag, add it *and* invalidate it.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 for your point. Certainly gave me some understanding on how it works. I would like to add one more point - **taxonomy_term_list** tag is already added in the list of drupal cache tags. How can I test if this works? I checked in the **cache_render** table but the particular row is still there when I update any terms.

Comment: Each entity type has a list tag, for example there is also `node_list` or `user_list`. Cache items are not deleted or modified when invalidated. The checksum of the cache item is no longer valid. Test it by rendering the node again and check if you get an old cached version or a new one.

Comment: Will the above code also work for a block which is attached to a certain region in the node page ? I basically have a facet filter block (facet filter names are specific taxonomy terms) . After implementing the above shared code I tried updating a certain term name which was already listed as a facet in the node page, but unfortunately the updated term does not reflect until I clear the cache.
Am I missing out any steps? Sorry for the lengthy question I didn't know a proper way to explain rather than giving example.

Comment: This should also work in a mymodule_preprocess_block() hook.

Comment: Thanks @4k4 ,`hook_preprocess_block()` works for normal blocks ,but facets are not getting updated. Maybe it has got nothing to do with caching, correct me if I'm wrong. I disabled caching and still the facets wont get updated. The catch here is my node has an entity field referring to a vocabulary and when I update the specific node and then reload the node page the facet is reflects with the updated term.

Comment: It still might be caching because you've said in the previous comment clearing the cache helps. After you've cleared the cache and executed one request the cache tables are rather empty, perhaps you are able to find the cache item responsible. About facets, it might be a good idea to ask a new question and provide details how you set it up.

Comment: Yeah that was a wrong finding on the earlier comment. Even after the cache is cleared and the table is empty ,the facets are not updated until the node is updated. Anyways as suggested I will post a new question.